# list of SML/NJ REPL commands

Tags: sml, read-eval-print-loop, smlnj

I'm looking for a full list of commands like `Ctrl-Z` that work in the SML/NJ REPL. I've searched here, Google and the SML/NJ website but can't find anything, not even the ones I already know.

To be clear, I'm not looking for an SML language reference, just the REPL interface commands.

Comment: What does `Ctrl-Z` do for you? For me it behaves as on every other console program: sends it to background.

Comment: This does not have to do at all with SML, this is a shell feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Z (under Windows I assume) is not necessarily a SML command. It rather colses the console instance. It means End-Of-File. Under Win you can see a simple application of this behavior by using:

```
copy con text.txt
```

This copies characters from the keyboard (con) to the text file. Many REPLs just use the same mechanism/understanding.

Largely the same exists under Unix/Linux systems with Ctrl-D.

Coming from here, there might be no more REPL commands for SML/NJ.

Comment: Within the REPL there are other Ctrl-sequences that do things:
Ctrl-h deletes the character to the left

Comment: ...continued...

Ctrl-i jumps forward 6 spaces
Ctrl-m seems to be <enter>

I remember Ctrl-m from other terminal programs.

I've just gone searching for a list of these commands, but all that comes up is commandline commands rather than keystrokes like ^M.

What started this search was the ability to clear the screen in the REPL. Is there such a console command?

Comment: It might be possible to clear the screen even without sml directly supporting it. I remember sml/nj as not the best REPL in terms of features (e.g. history). Under any Unix/Linux system sml can run in rlwrap. This then provides Ctrl-l as a shortcut to clear the screen. It also adds a few other nice features.